# Is it possible to upgrade xfce 4.12 to xfce 4.14 on Xubuntu 16.04.6?

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, xfce

I have downloaded xfce 4.14 tarball and extract it to a new directory. Can I install it on Xubuntu 16.04.6 which has xfce 4.12 ?
Or I need to run full desktop upgrade. thanks vladi
OS: Xubuntu 16.04.6 , xfce 4.12

Comment: No, it is not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update is in order anyway, for your Xubuntu 16.04 has reached its [End of Public Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL#Ubuntu_16.04_Xenial_Xerus). Xubuntu is on a three year support span for LTS versions, unlike the five year span for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, Ubuntu Base, and Ubuntu Kylin. Fortunately, they have published [Xubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://xubuntu.org/download).